# Powershell Auditing effective windows share permissions and outputting to CSV

Tags: windows, powershell, file-permissions, auditing

Powershell noob here. I'm trying to create a script that will take a list of users, a list of network shares, enumerate effective permissions for the user/share and output to CSV for audit purposes.

I've had success using [GetPACEffectiveAccess from the PowerShellAccessControl Module on Technet gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShellAccessControl-d3be7b83) to do the enumeration, but am getting completely stuck on how to output this data to CSV how I want it.

The code I have is pretty simple:

```
$users=gc C:\scripts\users.txt 
$shares=gc C:\scripts\shares.txt

foreach ($user in $users) {

foreach ($share in $shares) {
Get-PACEffectiveAccess -Path $share -Principal $user | select-object principal, accessmask, path | Export-Csv C:\scripts\EffectivePermissions\Audit.csv -append -NoTypeInformation}}
```

Since I have no idea how to do tables on StackOverflow (wow I am bad at this) I have attached a screenshot of the output I am getting from my simple script, and then the output I would like to get.

[image: Table output image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

After you gather the data, instead of outputting straight to the csv, you could add it to a two dimensional array, format it the way you'd like, and outfile it to a csv.